# can't forecast after fit my model to my data with LSTM

Tags: lstm, forecasting, lstm-stateful, bilstm

how to reshape my model to get forecast into future ,,I try to reshape alot but i think there is another problem hope to get answer

```
  TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'lstm' (type LSTM).
    
    'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'lstm' (type LSTM):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=<unknown>, dtype=float32)
      • mask=None
      • training=False
      • initial_state=None
THANK you  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```